# Can mobilenet in some cases perform better than inception_v3 and inception_resnet_v2?

Tags: image-recognition, tensorflow, pretrained-models

I have implemented a multi-label image classification model where I can choose which model to use, I was surprised to find out that in my case mobilenet_v1_224 performed much better (95% Accuracy) than the inception models (around 88% Accuracy), I'm using pretrained models (that I download from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) and adding a final layer that I train on my own data (3000 images). I wanted to get your opinion and see if maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: it's totally possible that `mobilenet` can perform better than `inception_resnet_v2`. I don't think you're necessarily doing something wrong. One thing which I can suggest is to repeat your experiments and see if you obtain the same result.